# How to make a windows virtualbox host recognise android usb?

Tags: virtualbox, android, smartphone

I want to root my phone (Micromax A52) and i got the procedure.

But I use Ubuntu for everyday use and now for rooting i need Windows.

I installed it in virtualbox. Now in vbox,the usb device is recognised only if ubuntu recognizes it.(all after installing the extention pack and adding the user to the vboxusers group)

But with the phone off for the flash process, how can i make the guest windows recognise the phone as ubuntu does not recognise

I know its not a specific ubuntu question, but as the host os in ubuntu,I asked it here!

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you: your question seems to be how to make a client windows install recognize a usb-device that is connected to an ubuntu-host, but is shut off? I suppose no machine sees a turned-off device, so how would you be able to make any OS (apart from the host/client question) see it?

Comment: windows recognizes a switched off android device through adb drivers...

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo addgroup vboxusers
```

and you can use usb connetion

Comment: Hi Enes Kuray, I have noticed, all of your answers are all of low quaility, which means they are very short and don't explain the answer in some cases to the OP clearly. Can you edit your answers and update them to have more information regarding each answer and explain with a longer, more detailed format each answer. This way yo help not only the one that is asking the question, but new users. Keep up the good work.

Comment: Why did you write publicy?  Of course i know you can do it with private messsage

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-system-tools
```

To add your username to the vboxusers group in Ubuntu, go to System > Administration > Users and Groups, click on "Manage groups", scroll down to the "vboxusers" group and click "Propreties", then check the box next to your username and click OK: go to restart computer that all, work with me :D

Comment: This definitely made USB devices appear under virtualbox including phone and webcam for me. Now need to see if I can use them!!